# Create only one role for Customer Community Plus users

Tags: customer-community, customer-portal

We're quickly approaching our 50k limit for Portal Roles in Salesforce, but based on things I've tried it seems like each new Customer Community Plus user requires a new Role?

I tried:

- Creating a new generic role (can't mark it as `Customer Role` )
- Re-assigning a different `Customer Role` from one Community user to another (error)
- Removing the role from the Community user (error)

I'd love to have just one Customer Community role that gets assigned to any new Community user since our Account object is Private (so even if all users are in the same role, records from one Community user wouldn't be shared to others).

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to follow up on this, the correct way to do this is to activate the feature `Minimize the number of roles created, which improves performance by cutting down processing loads` - found in Setup > Sharing Settings > Other Settings.

When new Community users are created after this is activated, they'll all get the same role.  More details here: https://www.learnexperiencecloud.com/s/article/Configure-Account-Role-Optimization-to-Help-You-Scale-Your-Experience-Cloud-Users